# One activity is in background and other in foreground ,

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

What I want to do is -

My application is in running state and I pause the app **i.e**. move it to the background. And user locks the screen and then unlocks it, so for ACTION_USER_PRESENT i want to start an advertisement activity from my app. But the activity in background should be there in the background and the one shown in the foreground is handled seperately . But if the click option from foreground activity is performed , it should close the foreground activity and launch the background activity.

Problem is -  When the User present intent is fired, then the new activity i launch , and restarts the activity that have been paused. But i dont want this, is the app was in background. Only the activity newly started should be shown  in the front.

From the receiver i am doing this to start the new activity :

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, MyAd.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

To start a quite new Activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyAd.class);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Because `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` will resume the old opened activity from the stack.

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK If set, this activity will become the start of
>   a new task on this history stack.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

And if you only want to keep an Activity instant in Activity Stack. Use

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: I am starting this new task from a broadcast receiver of action_user_present and without using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ..I get this exception    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: So try this `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`